# Bootstrap Material Design with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack, material-design, redux

perhaps a really rookie webpack question, but here i go:

Was wondering (since i really havent found any direct answers) if anyone could give me a hint on how to get [bootstrap material design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) working? I get the css stuff going for me but not the ripples.js stuff...

my webpack setup, well bits of it:

```
  ...
plugins: [ new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: "jquery", jQuery: "jquery" }) ],
module: {
loaders: [
       { test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel' },
       { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
       { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
       { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000" },
       { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
       { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
]
}
...
```

in my react's index.js which is where it all starts:

```
...
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
require('bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css')
require('bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.min.css')
...
```

how would i get the material.js and ripples.js to work?

i get no console errors or webpack errors, but the darn ripples are not showing! i am guessing there is a smart webpack way to get this all running or do i need to require the .js explicitly in my index.js (that has not worked)?

thanks in advance,

hanto899

**UPDATE:**
if i require the following in my index.js file:

```
 require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
require('bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css')
require('bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.min.css') 

require('bootstrap')
var material = require('bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.js') // not sure if the "var material =" is necessary here...
var ripples = require('bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.js') // not sure if the "var material =" is necessary here...

let $ = require('jquery')
$.material.init()
```

i get no errors, but ripple doesnt work. but... if i navigate to another page, and add, while on that page, :

```
let $ = require('jquery')
$.material.init()
```

webpack hot-reloads and then i get the ripple working. howerver if i refresh the page, i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

....

Comment: you can yse require for get them in your app through webpack.

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: i have solved it and updated my answer please take a look [here is my testes repo](https://github.com/jorawarsingh/es6-webpack-bootstrap-material-design) try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got it working.

You can simply import them as follows

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-material-design-master/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css";
import "bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.css";
import "bootstrap-material-design-master/dist/js/material.js";
import 'bootstrap-material-design-master/dist/js/ripples.js';
```

Then you need to call

```
$.material.ripples()
```

> $.material.ripples() will apply ripples.js to the default elements.

Comment: this I assume is in the index.js file? and then what, do I use these explicitly, or does it work since the bundeling will sort out the dependencies to these 2 variables?

Comment: bundling will sort out. webpack give a unique id to each required file so it doesn't get mixed up

Comment: hmm, still no ripples, i am trying on a:
  <button className="btn btn-raised btn-info">Hey</button>

Comment: if webpack is unable to find ripple it file give you erron on bundling, do you get error there?

Comment: do i need to init matieral in some other way?

Comment: var ripple = require("bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.js");
just worked for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120276/discussion-between-hanto899-and-jorawar-singh).

Comment: Yes, i managed to get it half-working with that aswell. however, it seems i have to add it to all my react components, in for example componentDidMount function. It would be nice to have it initialized globally only once... but perhaps that might not be possible...(?), would your example work if where to navigate to another "page"-component? or say that u land on another page-component initially, for me that doesnt work as i expect. If that works for you, i will mark your answer :)

Comment: I think it should be possible. If you have a main file where you bootstrap your react app you could add your files there and it should be available in whole app.

Comment: i have my main index.js file were i set up the react-router and combine the reducers to a single store. thats where i have the css, which works globally. I did try to put it there but the ripple does not seem to propagate down...

Comment: Can you set github repo and send me link I will look into that.

Comment: i think your original query regarding how to import bootstrap-material-design  with webpack is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer by [@MrJSingh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5409081/mrjsingh) and [@Rob Kielty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411902/rob-kielty) was not working for me.

So, I did some necessary modifications. Hope this will help.

In your entry point file (i.e. index.js in my project), import the files as follows

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css';
import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.min.js';
```

Then call

```
$.material.init();
```

Find my webpack configuration is [here](https://github.com/nunisa/react-practice/blob/master/scratch-react/webpack.config.js)