# webpack: errors in bootstrap.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, material-design

I am running:

*webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors*

and getting these errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/config.js:99:33
    at Array.map (native)
    at preparePluginsArray (/var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/config.js:64:20)
    at module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/config.js:32:28)
    at new module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo.js:21:19)
    at /var/www/node_modules/postcss-svgo/dist/index.js:91:16
    at Object.creator [as postcssSvgo] (/var/www/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:150:35)
    at /var/www/node_modules/cssnano/dist/index.js:276:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /var/www/node_modules/cssnano/dist/index.js:263:29
    at creator (/var/www/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:150:35)
    at processCss (/var/www/node_modules/css-loader/lib/processCss.js:183:16)
    at Object.module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader.js:22:2)
 @ ./~/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css
```

and:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./~/bootstrap-webpack/bootstrap-styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-webpack/bootstrap.config.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/config.js:99:33
    at Array.map (native)
    at preparePluginsArray (/var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/config.js:64:20)
    at module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/config.js:32:28)
    at new module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo.js:21:19)
    at /var/www/node_modules/postcss-svgo/dist/index.js:91:16
    at Object.creator [as postcssSvgo] (/var/www/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:150:35)
    at /var/www/node_modules/cssnano/dist/index.js:276:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /var/www/node_modules/cssnano/dist/index.js:263:29
    at creator (/var/www/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:150:35)
    at processCss (/var/www/node_modules/css-loader/lib/processCss.js:183:16)
    at Object.module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader.js:22:2)
 @ ./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./~/bootstrap-webpack/bootstrap-styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-webpack/bootstrap.config.js
```

I have no clue what is wrong here. Can someone give me a hint?

Here is the **index.js**:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-webpack';
import 'ripples';
import 'bootstrap-material-design';
import 'bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css';


require('./style.less');

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import reducer from './reducer';
import { App } from './containers';

import { fetchSuggestions, selectSuggestion } from './actions'

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, promise));

store.dispatch(fetchSuggestions()).then(() => {
    store.dispatch(selectSuggestion(store.getState().get('suggestions').first()));
});

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.material.init();
});
```

the **webpack.config.js**:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const TransferWebpackPlugin = require('transfer-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  entry: [path.join(__dirname, '/myapp/app/index.js')],
  // Render source-map file for final build
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // output config
  output: {
    path: buildPath, // Path of output file
    filename: 'app.js', // Name of output file
  },
  plugins: [
    // Define production build to allow React to strip out unnecessary checks
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
    }),
    // Minify the bundle
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        // suppresses warnings, usually from module minification
        warnings: false,
      },
    }),
    // Allows error warnings but does not stop compiling.
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    // Transfer Files
    new TransferWebpackPlugin([
      {from: 'html', to: 'html'},
      {from: 'img', to: 'img'},
    ], path.resolve(__dirname, 'myapp/static')),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // All .js files
        loaders: ['babel-loader'], // react-hot is like browser sync and babel loads jsx and es6-7
        exclude: [nodeModulesPath],
      },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' }, // use ! to chain loaders
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&minetype=application/font-woff2' },
    ],
  },
  styleLoader: require('extract-text-webpack-plugin').extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader')
};

module.exports = config;
```

and the **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.15.0",
  "description": "MyApp",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.config.js --progress --inline --colors --no-info",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.4",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.18.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "material": "^0.1.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.0",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "ripples": "0.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is requiring/importing the css file?

Comment: index.js added.

Comment: Might be same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796914/bootstrap-material-design-with-webpack#38796978

Comment: Looks like something in your CSS is not being handled correctly by loaders. Could be CSS, could be a file being loaded via `file-loader` or something similar (SVG?) that's referenced in your CSS and handled by another loader. Or your loader config could have an issue. The `--display-error-details` flag for webpack might give you more info on where the error is occurring? (maybe not)